# random matching data.table with duplicate enteries in R

Tags: r, join, data.table, sample

I have two data tables: `claims` and `SC`. They have one column in common - `subCoverageKey`. In `claims` I want to create a new columns `subCoverageeyClaim`. For every row in claims I want to take the corresponding `subCoverageeyClaim` value from `SC` - aka. matching by `subCoverageKey`. In case there are multiple `subCoverageeyClaim` for a `subCoverageKey` a random choice should be taken.

How can this be done?

I tried using sample() but couldn't get it to work.

The resulting data.table should look something like this:

```
claims
         clientID                                 claimID claimYear amount     clDate   subCoverageKey                  subCoverageKeyClaims
      1:        1 OP_a19517b1-5c66-47ca-92de-40c1b1a0b16b      2019  50.01 2019-04-26 IP_accommodation  b83f2a41-64c3-4571-97e7-6534f9629104
      2:        1 OP_a19517b1-5c66-47ca-92de-40c1b1a0b16b      2019  50.01 2019-04-26        IP_bundle f0a9ee55e-31b1-46f8-a0d4-91154e6c0998
      3:        1 OP_a19517b1-5c66-47ca-92de-40c1b1a0b16b      2019  50.01 2019-04-26 IP_accommodation f0a9ee55e-31b1-46f8-a0d4-91154e6c0998
      4:        1 OP_064c03aa-f2d5-4768-9c4e-51b54a725e56      2019  78.25 2019-06-09       IP_upgrade 74390be79-dc1e-4f7a-a0c0-f548c0b9ffcb
      5:        1 OP_064c03aa-f2d5-4768-9c4e-51b54a725e56      2019  78.25 2019-06-09       Daily_cash  7a61bcf3-9e6d-4c4b-be2b-1381527dedd6
     ---                                                                                                                                    
2637586:   130999 OP_b165c233-cd77-461b-b37d-704ac647d878      2019   8.66 2019-09-13       IP_upgrade  ffdef3f3-2996-4d1a-bf51-a78b43029079
2637587:   130999 OP_0a11b09d-fd4c-427e-ad7b-8c67c2fa70e5      2019  61.16 2019-09-17       Daily_cash  0a9ee55e-31b1-46f8-a0d4-91154e6c0998
2637588:   131000 OP_3fb03980-8642-48bf-8967-55e410243868      2019  12.64 2019-05-10       IP_upgrade  4390be79-dc1e-4f7a-a0c0-f548c0b9ffcb
2637589:   131000 OP_64d85cc6-db73-408a-a02a-6b0c811ee06d      2019   8.44 2019-05-02        IP_bundle  ffdef3f3-2996-4d1a-bf51-a78b43029079
2637590:   131000 OP_8b5585d8-d8e0-47ed-9005-3584062d4103      2019   3.57 2019-03-10 IP_accommodation  ffdef3f3-2996-4d1a-bf51-a78b43029079
```

The data.table i am planning to join are quite large with ~300000 observations, so i am looking for something that wont take that much time.

Comment: Lousy reproducible example. (1) One of the data.table was not reproducible because of `.internal.selfref`, (2) The names of the data.tables is missing, so the one helping needs to figure it out which is claims, (3) there are no matches in the example given, (4) The data examples surely can be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer i was looking for :

1. convert SC table into a list

```
listSC <- split(SC, SC$subCoverageKeyClaims)
```

2. use sapply randomly pick the corresponding subCoverageKeyClaims

```
claims$subCoverageKeyClaims <- sapply(claims$subCoverageKey, function(x){
      sample(listSC[[x]]$subCoverageKey, 1)
    })
```

Comment: But you do have duplicate values `subCoverageKey` column in `claims` , right? and you still want to maintain the number of rows in `claims` ?

Comment: yes, there are duplicated and yes, i want to keep all the rows in claims

Answer (score 0):

Here is one `tidyverse` way :

```
library(tidyverse)

SC %>%
  select(claimID, subCoverageKey) %>%
  group_by(subCoverageKey) %>%
  nest %>%
  ungroup %>%
  right_join(claims, by = 'subCoverageKey') %>%
  mutate(subCoverageKeyClaims = map_chr(data, ~sample(.x$claimID, 1)))
```

Since there are duplicates in `claims` dataset we create a list column for same `subCoverageKey` in `SC` and join it with `claims` dataset. We can then select one random `claimID` value from their respective data.

Comment: what is the difference between this and the solution that i have provided below?

Comment: Difference as in? If you mean in terms of output then both of them should give the same output.